# Change Firefox timeout for TITLE popup?

Tags: firefox

[Some websites](http://xkcd.com) use the TITLE tag to display relevant information in a tooltip popup when the cursor is on the relevant content.

**Problem:** The tooltip disappears after a few seconds, and this is often not enough time to read the entire TITLE tag.

**Question:** How can I extend this timeout? Is there a setting in Firefox about:config that controls it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin should do the trick. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11233/

Also it's the alt property not the title tag.

Comment: +1 for the plugin - that looks good.
Also, for XKCD which I linked to, the `ALT` tag just has the comic's title (ironically), but the alternate punchline really is in the `TITLE` tag.

Comment: Marked as accepted - but others should note that Firefox 3.6 doesn't need this anymore because the behaviour has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin suggested by Daisetsu indicates that this behaviour has been deemed [a bug which is solved](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=395668) in Firefox 3.6. So instead of installing the plugin, one could upgrade to Firefox 3.6 and have the same effect (with the added benefit of a newer browser).